# RegEx for sequence that could contain the delimiter

Tags: regex

I have a line of text that contains different sets of characters separated by a

`space dash space (" - ")`.

```
005 - 0000 - 2310 - Storage - Summer
007 - 0000 - 1610 - Legal - Criminal Law
007 - 0000 - 8921 - Legal - Civil - Zoning
002 - 0000 - 2410 - Planning
123 - 0000 - 2510 - Finance/Corporate
008 - 0000 - 2520 - Legal - Technical Patents
321 - 0000 - 2610 - Clients & Storage
```

I am trying to find a RegEx that would allow me to grab all the text after the third dash even if it contains dashes. So for the aboce lines the text I would like to capture would be ..

```
Storage - Summer
Legal - Criminal Law
Legal - Civil - Zoning
Planning
Finance/Corporate
Legal - Technical Patents
Clients & Storage
```

This text I would like to capture could contain any number of dashes. I just know that the section I want to capture starts after the third dash. Also, I cannot count on the number groups all being the same in length. How do I define the RegEx to start capturing everything after the third space dash space?

I tried the following ...

```
(.*) - (.*) - (.*)
```

But it could not handle multiple dashes after the third `space dash space`

Comment: What flavor of regex are you using?

Comment: I will be using the .NET regex library

Comment: `^[^-]+-[^-]+-[^-]+- ` works in sublime text to match what you want eliminated.

Comment: Do you have access to the C# code? You may solve the issue without a regex.

Comment: Just for reference, [here is the C# demo](https://ideone.com/1AFQe2)

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`^(?:.*?-){3}\s+(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/jc03pJ/3), which makes use of non-greedy matching.

This will capture anything after whitespace following the third dash.

```
^                       // asserts position at start of line
(                       // start of group
  ?:                    // non-matching group
    .*?                 // matches any character lazily
    -                   // matches a -
){3}                    // matches 3 times
\s+                     // matches 1 or more whitespace
(                       // start of group 1
  .*                    // matches any character
)                       // end of group 1
$                       // asserts position at end of line
```

Comment: @webworm added an explanation.